# How to use \tableofcontents well?

Tags: table-of-contents

I´m trying and trying and the results are bad.

Sometimes, `\tableofcontents` use red text, other point to a page that is incorrect.
If a part is in page 3, the TOC point to page 2.

Are there any package that runs well?, or.. how can I use `\tableofcontents` with good results?

[TEX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3jmpf2sqa8bd5h/TFG-Replanteado-001-Stack.tex)
[PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz48gicqmx14vfz/TFG-Replanteado-001-Stack.pdf)

--------------  edited after Crhistopher comments -----

In this image you can see what I obtain and what I would like to obtain

[image]

Inm this code I view in TOC that 3 last items poit to page 4, when in reality they are in page 5.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  % Margenes de la normativa TFG

\usepackage{setspace} % para que no afecte el interlineado a las notas de pié de página
\usepackage{blindtext}  % para usar un texto-tipo de ejmplo Lore.... sin teclear a boleo, con \blindtext
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}  % otra opcion sería \usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
\usepackage{datetime}       % paquete para configurar formato de fecha y hora
\settimeformat{ampmtime}
\renewcommand*{\noon}{\pmname}

% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\part{Introducción General}


\part{Esquema de Funcionamiento}
\blindtext

\section{Búsqueda Tabú (Tabu Search)}
\blindtext
\section{Enfriamiento Simulado}
\blindtext
\section{Algoritmos Genéticos}


\part{Ejemplos de Aplicaciones Simples}
\blindtext
\section{Búsqueda Tabú (Tabu Search)}
\blindtext
\section{Enfriamiento Simulado}
\blindtext
\section{Algoritmos Genéticos}

\part{Análisis de su funcionamiento}

\section{Búsqueda Tabú (Tabu Search)}
\section{Enfriamiento Simulado}

\section{Algoritmos Genéticos}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps, there are missing `\phantomsection` statements. And the answer to your question whether there are any packages, that run well, is **yes**.

Comment: In addition to my first comment: The `.tex` file you provided in your dropbox is not working due to some `\input` statements for files not being available.

Comment: @christian-hupfer, what is phantomsection for?

Comment: If you set `\setstretch{1.5}` there is no wonder why you obtain such large vertical distances.

Comment: @MikaIke You've got several questions here, at least some of which have been covered before (the StackExchange format works best with one-question-per-post). For example, the lines being red is due to `hyperref`'s defaults: `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` should deal with that. Perhaps consider asking a series of very focussed questions.

Answer (score 1):

the TOC generated by \tableofcontents 1st need to be twice compiled, if after that the links are wrong check your chapter/section/subsection's labels maybe they all are labeled the same that causes links to be bad, also the place you put labels must be right after chapter/section/subsection is declare:

```
\section[Section 1]{ Section 1 some Book}\labe{Sec-1}
\section[Section 2]{ Section 2 some Book}\labe{Sec-1}
```

if that doesn't work also try load this pack in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[pdftex=true,colorlinks=true,plainpages=true]{hyperref} %PDFLaTex
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
```

Comment: Yes, It´s possible that the solution to avoid problems is compile twice. :-)) increible!!!